# Solve DE by Laplace transformation: $y'' + y = 8e^{-2t} \sin t$?

Tags: laplace-transform

The differential equation is as follows

$$\begin{cases}
y'' + y = 8e^{-2t} \sin t \\
y(0)=0 \\y'(0)=0
\end{cases}$$

How do I solve it by Laplace transformation?

In my solution I've taken the Laplace transform of both sides and got to the solution of the transformed equation $$\mathcal L\{y\} = \frac{8}{[(s-2)^2+1](s^2+1)}$$ but I'm stuck, I don't know how to take the inverse Laplace transform to get the solution to the DE.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  This looks like a pretty straightforward problem.  How far did you get and and where are you stuck?

Comment: I am here y(s) =8/[(s+2)^2+(1)^2】[s^2+1] and then I will apply laplace inverse to y(s) and I m not able to factorise the denominator and partial fraction so that I can get a,b,c or d value

Comment: Good! Please put that into the body of your question.  We have a real problem here with students just pasting their homework into the box and expecting full solutions.  Showing that you're not one of those students will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods that can be used. The first being the convolution and the second being the longer, more standard, version. 
Let the Laplace transform be given by
$$\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\} = f(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} \, y(t) \, dt.$$
Since, 
$$\mathcal{L}\{ y'' + y\} = s^2 \, f - s y(0) - y'(0) + f = (s^2 + 1) \, f,$$
then by convolution the solution takes the form:
\begin{align}
y(t) = 8 \, \int_{0}^{t} \cos(t-u) \, e^{-2 u} \, \sin(u) \, du.
\end{align}
This is seen by
\begin{align}
(s^2 + 1) \, f &= \mathcal{L}\{8 \, e^{-2t} \, \sin(t) \} \\
f &= \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \, \mathcal{L}\{8 \, e^{-2t} \, \sin(t) \} \\
&= \mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)\} \cdot \mathcal{L}\{8 \, e^{-2t} \, \sin(t) \}
\end{align}
and after the inversion, by convolution, the integral form, which can be calculated, is obtained.

The more standard version is:
\begin{align}
(s^2 + 1) \, f &= \mathcal{L}\{8 \, e^{-2t} \, \sin(t) \} = \frac{8}{(s+2)^2 + 1} \\
f &= \frac{8}{(s^2 + 1) \, ((s+2)^2 + 1)} \\
&= \frac{1-s}{s^2 + 1} + \frac{s+3}{(s+2)^2 + 1} \\
&= \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} - \frac{s}{s^2+1} + \frac{s+2}{(s+2)^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{(s+2)^2 + 1}
\end{align}
and leads to
$$y(t) = \sin t - \cos t + e^{-2 t} \, (\sin t + \cos t).$$

Both methods yield the same result after some calculations are applied for the convolution case.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

> Apply Laplace transform to both sides of the equation to get $$ s^2 \tilde y -s \underbrace{y(0^+) - y'(0^+)}_{\text{Zero from the}\\\text{initial conditions}} + \tilde y = \frac{8}{(s+2)^2+1} \\[20 pt] s^2\tilde y + \tilde y = \frac{8}{(s+2)^2+1}$$
>   Where $\tilde y = \mathcal L\{y\}$. Now you can easily solve for $\tilde y$ and do an inverse Laplace transform to find the solution $y$.

By simplifying the solution you'll get $$\tilde y = \frac{8}{[(s+2)^2+1](s^2+1)}$$ and by doing partial fraction decomposition $$\tilde y = \frac{As+B}{(s+2)^2+1}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+1} = \frac{(As+B)[(s+2)^2+1]+(Cs+D)(s^2+1)}{[(s+2)^2+1](s^2+1)}$$ Now just find the values of $A,B,C,D$ and then take the inverse Laplace of the decomposed function.

Comment: that I have done but failed to apply laplace inverse

Comment: Try and apply long division $$\tilde y = \frac{32}{(4-s^2)(1+s^2)} = \frac{A}{4-s^2}+\frac{B}{1+s^2}$$ Just find the values of  $A$ and $B$ and try taking the inverse Laplace on that

Comment: What is Laplace of 8 e^-2t sint ? It is simple but I m confused

Comment: How did u got 32/(4-s^2)(1+s^2)(1+s^2) because my answer is different

Comment: Ops, i made a mistake, let me correct my answer

Comment: @DiwakarYadav $L(e^{at} f(t))(s)=L(f(t))(s-a)$ in general